# Will not return MYSQLI Results for username

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to return a username when a user forgets their username.  I have it validating again their email address but for some reason it just keeps saying 'Error: cannot find username'. I am using the correct mysqli syntax I hope.

```
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $username = "";
    if (!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)) {
        $errmsg = 'Error: ' . $email . ' is not a valid email address';
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT email FROM admin WHERE email = '$email'";
        $results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        $query2 = mysqli_fetch_array($results);

        if ($query2 == 0) {
            $errmsg = 'Error: ' . $email . ' is not found, please try again';
        }
        if (!errmsg) {
            $getuname = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '$email'";
            if (!mysqli_query($con, $getuname)) {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($getuname);
        }
        $username = '<div class="registersuccess">Your username is: ' . $row['username'] . '</div>';
    }
    $username = '<div class="registererror">Error: cannot find username</div>';

    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

I am a noob when it comes to this but am pretty sure this is correct.  if not where did i go wrong?

Comment: For one thing, you should use `preg_match` instead of `eregi` which has been deprecated plus a mix of `mysql_` and `mysqli_` make for *disaster in progress.*

Comment: Looks like you're setting the "cannot find" value outside of the if statement so it's always being hit. If your code was formatted properly this would be a lot easier to notice.

Comment: No need of 2 different queries, you can do it in one only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some mistake in your code, you can see the mistake in Mark B and Amal Murali's answer.  Let me make your `else` block simple and more clear. you can use only 1 query instead of 2 queries.

```
else {
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '$email'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if (!$errmsg){
        if($numrows == 0) {
            $errmsg = 'Error: '.$email.' is not found, please try again'; 
                // or here you can add message like Cannot find username
        }
        else
        {
            $username = '<div class="registersuccess">Your username is: '.$row['username'].'</div>';
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

These are some of the errors I noticed:

- You're doing `if (!errmsg)` but there's no such constant and you want `if (!$errmsg)` instead.
- As Marc B pointed out, you're doing `$row = mysql_fetch_array($getuname);` but you want `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($getuname);` instead.

Also, the specific problem you're describing is probably because of the `$username` declaration just before the `mysqli_close` statement. You're resetting the value of `$username` there and it'd always echo out the same message regardless of the result of your database query.

```
$username = "";
if(condition)
{
    # code ...
}
else
{
    # code ...
}
$username = '<div class="registererror">Error: cannot find username</div>';
mysqli_close($con);
```

That's one of the many logical mistakes in your code. Structure the `if-else` blocks with proper indentation and you shouldn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a disaster. You're using `ereg`, which has been deprecated since the stone age. You're mixing calls to the mysql (no `i`) and the mysqli (with `i`) libraries. They are NOT interchangeable and are NOT compatible with each other.

You need to switch over to the `preg` functions, and standardize on a SINGLE mysql library. Since `mysql` is deprecated as well, use `mysqli` ONLY.

```
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($getuname);
               ^^^---note the LACK of an i

if (!errmsg){
    ^^^--note the lack of a $ sign, meaning this is undefined/undeclared constant.
```

Comment: I feel I should point out that although this answer contains good advice, it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: How could the OP possibly EVER get a username out of the database if they're not even running the queries/retrieving the data properly to begin with? That's like complaining there's a dead bug on your car's windshield, after driving it over a cliff and it exploding into a million pieces.

Comment: Ya gotta love Marc's analogies ;-) I remember the "postman" bit; *classic.*

Answer (score 0):

Change this section of code:

```
    if (!errmsg){
      $getuname = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '$email'";
      if (!mysqli_query($con,$getuname))
        {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($getuname);
    }       
    $username = '<div class="registersuccess">Your username is: '.$row['username'].'</div>';
 }
 $username = '<div class="registererror">Error: cannot find username</div>';
```

to:

```
    if (!errmsg){
      $getuname = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '$email'";
      $uresult = mysqli_query($con, $getuname);
      if (!$uresult))
        {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($uresult);
      if ($row) {
        $username = '<div class="registersuccess">Your username is: '.$row['username'].'</div>';
      } else {
        $username = '<div class="registererror">Error: cannot find username</div>';
    }
  }
```

Your mistakes:

- You were calling `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`.
- You were passing the SQL string to `mysql_fetch_array`, not the result of `mysqli_query`.
- You weren't checking whether a row was returned, you were just setting `$username` unconditionally -- first to the success message, then to the failure message.